# ToneJS observe Player current time

Tags: javascript, typescript, tonejs

I've been trying to figure out how to observe the player's current time but without luck. I tried the immediate(), now(), and some other time-related API from the documentation.

https://tonejs.github.io/docs/14.7.77/Player.html

And also I tried several properties from the BaseContext. No luck so far.

Basically, I want to build a music player and display the current time played just like a regular music player. This should be possible for any audio library.

Answer (score 0):

Going through some of the [github issue posts for tonejs](https://www.google.com/search?q=tonejs%20get%20players%20current%20time%20site:github.com&newwindow=1&sxsrf=ALiCzsbJ7F_MSamlFd95dL_mBfOT42HV8w:1653090966683&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi21-beo-_3AhVog2oFHSNMAkUQrQIoBHoECAwQBQ&biw=1440&bih=715&dpr=2) for this, it appears adding this functionality will bring a lot of performance issues.

However, if you are simply wanting to get the amount of time the tone has been playing I don't see why you couldn't just save the start time in a variable and then subtract?

```js
const startTime = Date.now();
const displayTime = Date.now() - startTime; // time in milliseconds
```

Save the `startTime` when you call the start method for the tone, then every render update the current time with `displayTime`. It is given in milliseconds, that you could then convert too `mm:ss`.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm looking for. I want to be able to calculate the remaining and the running time of the player.

Answer (score 0):

To get the position of the Tone.js player without the transport running, you can use the `player.start` method to schedule the playback and then query the position. Here's how you can do it:

1. Create your player and connect it to the desired source.
2. Schedule the player to start at the desired time using the `start` method.
3. Query the player's position using the `player.position` property.

Here's some example code:

```js
const Tone = require('tone');

// Create a player
const player = new Tone.Player('your-audio-file.mp3').toDestination();

// Schedule the player to start at a specific time (e.g., 0 seconds)
player.start(0);

// Query the player's position
const position = player.position;

// Log the position to the console
console.log('Player position:', position);
```

By scheduling the start of the player at the desired time, you can access its position without the transport running. The `player.position` property will give you the current position in seconds, even if the transport is stopped.